# AWS Elasic Beanstalk : Retrieving environment URL from within instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

From within a Beanstalk instance, how can I programmatically retrieve the URL for my environment?

I need to know this because the instances need to know whether they are running in production or

I couldn't find it using Platform Scripts `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config ...` or Instance Metadata with `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hints from @dannosaur I found the solution. I'll post a new answer since there is a lot more to mention.

The Elastic Beanstalk API command `aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --region <your-region> --environment-id <your-environment-id>` gives you lots of good information. Or leave out the `--environment-id` to describe all your environments. To get the URL specifically we can do:

`aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --region us-east-2 --environment-id e-sfmsdjhtwn --query "Environments[0].CNAME"`

**But**, for this to work we need to grant an extra permission to the IAM role that is associated with the EC2 instance. So go to IAM > Roles > aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role > Add inline policy. Select the following: Service=Eleastic Beanstalk, Actions=DescribeEnvironments, Resources=All resources. Complete creating the policy.

**And also**, this requires us to know the environment ID our current instance is in. But we can even find that programmatically in `/etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties` (requires root access).

So with the use of `.ebextensions` we can now act upon this in our deployment scripts.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only get this from the Elastic Beanstalk API, as follows;

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments \
    --region <your-region> \
    --environment-names <your-environment-name> \
    --query "Environments[0].CNAME"
```

The above will output;

```
"your-eb-cname.aws-region.elasticbeanstalk.com"
```

Comment: Yeah that kind of works - but not readily from within the instance though. Just get an empty array environments. Probably because it's not authenticated...

Comment: The IAM role that's associated to the EC2 instance needs to have the "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironments" permission.